# My prefix is used when facing ascent

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is used when facing ascent,
>
> my infix falls before important events.
>
> My suffix is served in youth,
>
> I present an unknown truth.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> REVEAL?

My prefix is used when facing ascent,

> Gotta REV the engine to get up the hill.

my infix falls before important events.

> On the EVE of battle, the EVE of destruction, Christmas EVE, etc.

My suffix is served in youth,

> VEAL is the meat of a young calf.

I present an unknown truth.

> You REVEAL the truth.

Comment: Right again! :-)